# How to read arbitrary commandline arguments in Play framework?

Tags: playframework, frameworks

I would like to be able to invoke play with arbitrary command-line arguments like such :

$ play "run arg1 arg2"

or

$ play "run var1=val1 var2=val2"

And then be able to access either those arguments as an array or map from within my play application.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?